# Automatically Create regular bridge between cylinders

Tags: modifiers

I want to create bridge automatically between two long objects like cylinders. Does anyone know how to create bridge as the screenshot shows easily(Figure 1)? I know by union and remesh, it can create something similar, but the mesh will be irregular(Figure 3).
Any hint will be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my files:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ele0gddjpxgnyy6/AACs0OizY_RklNubc7yT7rT4a?dl=0

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: it's hard to figure out what your trying to do, from that one screenshot.
try adding more screenshots of different perspective and modes or just try to share the blend file.
it would be easy for others to understand your issue

Comment: @Nand27 Yes, I have updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci1jBOm_5NY Adding holes in curved surfaces.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4F6Q6h2-ao Bridging edge loops.

Comment: I don't think using a union by adding a third cylinder would make it irregular.
also you can remesh it with a lower value like .05 if your not satisfied with the geometry.
Since this question seems to be answered I can't demonstrate it here.
I hope you got you answers.

Comment: @RonJensen Thank you for the links. However, these are manual operations.  I wish there will be something automatic. I need to work on more cylinders like these...